# Google Calendar, events of all calendars

Tags: calendar, gdata

I'm using the gdata library for java provided by Google. In particular I'm working on the Google Calendar lib, following the guide:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_java#RetrievingDateRange

Using Google Calendar, it is possible to add other calendars, for example about holydays, football and so on. The guide shows how to get events about your calendar but not about all calendars saved. 
How can I do it? It is weird because getting user events it returns a list of Entry about Events, but getting all events it returns a list of Entries about Calendars (applying more or less the same code)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer. I'll publish the link for who is interested.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-help-dataapi/YEnxdkQ2KhY